# Python Svmlight Error: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, svmlight

I'm running python 2.7.5 with scikit_learn-0.14 on my Mac OSX Mountain Lion.

Everything I run a svmlight command however, I get the following warning:

> DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error >in the future

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deprecation warning in scikit-learn svmlight format loader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084218/deprecation-warning-in-scikit-learn-svmlight-format-loader)

Answer (score 10):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084218/deprecation-warning-in-scikit-learn-svmlight-format-loader), it's Numpy 1.8.0 deprecation warning caused by indexing with non-integer in scikit-learn.  It won't affect the results.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the message?

Comment: Yes, with a warnings filter: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem when I assigned numbers to a matrix.
like this:
`Qmatrix[list2[0], list2[j]] = 1`

the component may be a non-integer number, so I changed to this:
`Qmatrix[int(list2[0]), int(list2[j])] = 1`

and the warning removed